# Python os.popen returns 68864 error

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a python program to automate certain windows commands which should lead to creation of an iso file which I can execute in Virtual box.

There are 4 commands last of which is "mkisofs -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -o filename.iso -b filename.flp cdiso/"

I used os.popen to execute the commands and I found that everything except this last command works fine.

From the object returned all I can get is the status code of 68864. I know it is not working because Virtual box returns an error when trying to load the iso file.

What might be going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you dealing with (base one and virtual environment)?

Comment: I am running WindowS 7. The virtual one is the new OS files I write on my own and execute. For this normally I need to execute 4 different commands on windows Command prompt, which I am trying to automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, errors returned by `popen` are the same as the `system()` library call. To extract the actual error you have to use the `WEXITSTATUS` macro.

Fortunately you have this functionality available as `os.WEXITSTATUS`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.WEXITSTATUS(68864)
13
```

I'm not sure of what it means, it probably prints some error to the console before terminating. Did you try to run the program manually?

A wild guess is that this `13` number is actually the `errno` that causes the failure. If that's the case, then:

```
>>> os.sterror(13)
'Permission denied'
```

Comment: I am running Windows and WEXITSTATUS does not seem to be available on Windows.

Comment: Also I have run it manually and it works fine. I think its a question of whether every command line instruction can be executed in python like this.

Comment: @SachinCNambiar: Oh, right, that is actually in `os.posix` but re-imported in `os` on POSIX systems. In Windows the exit code of the process should be returned directly, but I'm afraid that you are getting the Linux exit code conversion anyway (cygwin, mingw, or something like that in the way). Sorry but I cannot help further... other than advising you to use the excelent [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting ProcMon. Finally I was able to find out the issue. I compared the procmon logs for direct execution and through python.I found that till a point both look same, after which the mkisofs process gets closed when its run by python. I found from google, there is a bug in mkisofs,that everytime it encounters a file which does not have write access, it quits, rather than giving a warning and proceeding. So I changed the properties of mkisofs and made it "run as an administrator" it works. Thank you for your time